# Ember - Check if the application is in the loading route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have created a simple Ember Application and i need to know if the Application is currently loading. I have created the LoadingRoute, that works perfectly. Is there any startLoad and finishedLoad event?

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

Everything i have is this. I haven't found anything in the Documentation & Google. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the answer.. :/ Sorry for this Post

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function(){
      this._super();
      console.log("loading started..");
  },
  deactivate: function(){
      this._super();
      console.log("loading finished..");
  }
});
```